# Latex in Chaco text?

Tags: python, latex, enthought, traits, chaco

Is it possible to create a chaco plot with latex text?  For example, if we wanted latex symbols in the title of [this exampe](http://code.enthought.com/projects/chaco/docs/html/user_manual/tutorial_1.html):

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance
from traitsui.api import View, Item
from chaco.api import Plot, ArrayPlotData
from enable.component_editor import ComponentEditor
from numpy import linspace, sin

class LinePlot(HasTraits):
    plot = Instance(Plot)
    traits_view = View(
        Item('plot',editor=ComponentEditor(), show_label=False),
        width=500, height=500, resizable=True, title="Chaco Plot")

    def __init__(self):
        super(LinePlot, self).__init__()
        x = linspace(-14, 14, 100)
        y = sin(x) * x**3
        plotdata = ArrayPlotData(x=x, y=y)
        plot = Plot(plotdata)
        plot.plot(("x", "y"), type="line", color="blue")
        plot.title = "sin(x) * x^3"
        self.plot = plot

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LinePlot().configure_traits()
```

I tried replacing title with `$sin(x)^3$` to no avail, and wondered if this was possible?  Screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not (it is a matplotlib feature). But you could try to use unicode symbols for easy cases.